# How to write data into same file in MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have created a worker thread.
One thread prints the natural numbers by creating one .txt file and my intention is to open the same file and print even numbers.
I am able to print in different files by creating new .txt file in another thread.
But I need the same file (which is created by first thread) to be opened and print even numbers.
Please help me out.

Comment: Any idea how the data shall be in the file? Strings, binary? First all natural numbers then all even numbers? Or mixed in any order? Even numbers are natural numbers, so why not just write the natural numbers?

Comment: I am new to MFC.Learning threads .so i need to do sample program in threads like runnning one thread prints natural numbers and after that calling another thread that prints even numbers in the same file which i have crreated in first thread...

Comment: Please adjust your question to reflect that you are running two threads one after the other and not in parallel (without concurrency the task is much easier).

Comment: You opened the file in the first thread and wrote to it. Now after the first thread ended you can open the same file again and write to it again, just as you did in the first thread. So what exactly is the Problem? What have you tried, what did not work?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways I can think of to do this :

1. Use a critical section around the file open/write/close sections in each of the two threads (I think you'll probably need to close the file after each write before you release the critical section).
2. Use a third thread to do all the file writing and just pass messages from the other two threads to it to tell it what to write to file.